# How to properly make a production build in NextJS?

Tags: css, webpack, next.js

I am getting this error while I am building a production build of my app in NextJS. I was not seeing this error in the development version of my app.

[image: Here is the error]

Here is the error.

and here is my css code which this error is pointing to.

```
.seller_main_fourth{
   padding: 50px;
   min-height: 600px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   background: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/sell/images/bg/illustration-pf-home- 
      2x._CB441100178_.png) center right/700px no-repeat, url(https://m.media- 
      amazon.com/images/G/01/sell/images/illustration/pf-wave-horizon-1.svg) top left/cover no- 
      repeat;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did u try wrapping url in quotes(")?

Comment: @GautamNaik well wrapping in quotes worked. You can write an answer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping image url's in quotes

```css
.seller_main_fourth-edited {
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: url("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/sell/images/bg/illustration-pf-home-2x._CB441100178_.png") center right/700px no-repeat, url("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/sell/images/illustration/pf-wave-horizon-1.svg") top left/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="seller_main_fourth-edited">

</div>
```